# OverRide a DataRow's .Item Property to allow for DBNULLS

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have found that most of the programs I write usually incorporate `DataTables` and I am often pulling data from the table by selecting a `DataRow` (either via looping or Linq) and assinging my variables values by writing something along the lines of:

```
MyVar = ThisDataRow.Item("itm")
```

This works very well except for when the specific item is a `DBNull` in which case it raises an error.

Now, a simple fix is to write a simple function / if statement that either returns the value or `0` or `""` if the item's value is `DBNull`, but I'm wondering if it would make sense to somehow inherit the `DataRow` object and create a new property `ItemOrEmpty` (or whatever you want to call it) that won't raise the error and return the correct value back.

This would allow me to use either:

```
MyVar = ThisDataRow.Item("itm")
```

or

```
MyVar = ThisDataRow.ItemOrEmpty("itm")
```

Depending if I want to trap for `Nulls` or not.

My questions are:

1. I have no clue how I could do this and make a DataTable use this new object rather than a DataRow - Seems like I'd need to overload the `DataRow` object rather than create a new object, but I don't know how to do this.
2. Is this a good / bad idea? And why do you think so?
3. Would this add a substantial amount of overhead rather than just creating a simple function that I run the `DataRow.Item` through each time?

Basically, this is a fairly theoretical question - Is this good / bad overall and how could this be accomplished?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you considered an extension method?

Comment: Tim, that's EXACTLY what I was looking for!! - Thanks! If you want to post that as a solution, I'll award you the points. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness - For anyone who comes by this question - the way I ended up doing this was by taking @Tim's advice and writing my own extension method.
Please note that this is the first one I've ever written, so please let me know if there are better ways to write it.

```
''' <summary>
''' Returns the item from a DataRow and, if it is DBNull, it returns a specified default value
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ColumnName">The name of the Column in the datarow we want the value from.</param>
''' <param name="DefaultValue">The default value for that column if it is NULL.</param>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ItemOrEmpty(Of T)(ByVal dr As DataRow, ByVal ColumnName As String, ByVal DefaultValue As T) As T
    If dr.Item(ColumnName) Is Nothing Or IsDBNull(dr.Item(ColumnName)) Then
        Return DefaultValue
    Else
        Return dr.Item(ColumnName)
    End If
End Function
```

Hope this helps other people out there...

Comment: +1 for posting your solution for others to see.  I'm glad my comment helped :) I didn't post it as a solution because it wasn't - it was more like tossing a suggestion over the cube wall to a fellow developer.

Comment: ... To me it was substantially more than that - To a person who's never dealt with extension methods before, you opened my eyes to their possibility!! - Thank you @Tim